# Can I have Data Exported into Shared device automatically

Tags: data-export, schedule

I have a requirement where I should be able to export users on weekly basis and keep them in shared Device. By going through the salesforce docs it says that we can able to schedule data export but can we keep them in shared device along with this scheduled Export?. Any help please

Answer (score 2):

You can use native data export to export the data in the system. But when this process complete it send zip file to you on email which you need to manually download.

As per docs.

> Salesforce creates a zip archive of CSV files and emails the user who
>   scheduled the export when it’s ready. The email address for this
>   notification can’t be changed. Exports complete as soon as possible,
>   however we can't guarantee the date and time of completion. Large
>   exports are broken up into multiple files. To download the zip file,
>   follow the link in the email or click Data Export. Zip files are
>   deleted 48 hours after the email is sent.

[Export Backup Data from Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_exportdata.htm&type=5)

We also have one more option here. You can use Data loader CLI to schedule to export data from Salesforce and store that in you local system. This way you don't need to worry about download files from email in a time frame. This complete process will be automate and run in background.

You can find more details here: [Automate Salesforce Data Import/Export Using Data Loader CLI](https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/automate-salesforce-data-import-export-using-data-loader-cli)